# Compatibility with Apple Devices and Printers

Tags: compatibility

I am a Windows user from the past 8 years. So, I am new to this Linux interface.
I would like to know whether Apple devices like iPhone,iPad can be connected in Ubuntu.
And also I have a HP(Hewlett-Packard) Deskjet Printer. So, I would also like to know whether these type of printers work with Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

HP printers works with Linux, as dos other HP devices. As for Apples iPhones, iPads etc well sometimes, some of the mediaplayers have more support than others, try googling your devices with reguard to linux/ Ubuntu.